# Replace the first line of a file in android

Tags: java, android

In my android application i would like to replace my first line of a txt file with some other data.
Is there any way that i can do this.

Please let me know your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I believe you could just use the normal Java FileWriter, and write to a file on the SD card(or wherever). All the logic should be the same as a normal Java app, with added goodies to interact with files on the phone. Assuming you are writing/reading from a file on the phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the nature of Java IO and the disk file system, it is not directly possible to replace an arbitrary "line" of a file without taking the remnant of the file into consideration. You need to **fully** read and write the file.

The [`BufferedReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) and [`PrintWriter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) are helpful in this. The former offers a [`readLine()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) method and the latter offers a [`println()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println%28java.lang.String%29) method (which compensates the fact that the `readLine()` eats the newline). Add some `boolean` which you can use in the loop to determine if the first line has to be processed or not.